# Python 3+: While loop continues to ask user to Enter an Expense even if user inputs button to stop loop.

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
def getExpenses():
    userExpense = 0
    totalExpenses = 0
    moreExpenses = ""
    while moreExpenses != "y":
        userExpense = float(input("Enter an expense: "))
        totalExpenses = totalExpenses + userExpense
        moreExpenses = input("Do you have more expenses? Type y" +\
                             " to input more expenses, or any key for no: ")

    return totalExpenses
```

Edit: I was able to get it to go through the loop, but now the code keeps running through an asking to "Enter an expense," regardless of which button is pushed.

If full code is needed, here is the sequence of code beforehand:

```
##---Initializing Variable----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
monthlyIncome=0
monthlyExpenses=0
totalExpenses=0

##---Introductory Statement: Welcome to the Program---------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def intro():
    print("\n".join(["---------------------------------------------------------",
              "Hello and Welcome to the Budget Analyzer",
              "Get ready to find out how much money you'll have left $$$",
              "---------------------------------------------------------"]))
    return

##---The monthlyIncome mod. gets user input for income/mth to compare against expenses----------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def getIncome(): 
    monthlyIncome=float(input("Please enter the amount of money you'll have for the month: "))
    return monthlyIncome
```

This is the main module - I'm still trying to debug where the issue is, so I haven't finished parts of the program yet:

```
#---Run main module-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def main():
    intro()
    getIncome()
    getExpenses(monthlyIncome)
```

Comment: Where is the part where it calls intro()?

Comment: I added the main module that calls it in the above post.

Answer (score 1):

your code works, but probably not as you intended:

```
def getExpenses():
    userExpense = 0
    totalExpenses = 0
    moreExpenses = ""
    while moreExpenses != "y":
        userExpense = float(input("Enter an expense: "))
        totalExpenses = totalExpenses + userExpense
        moreExpenses = input("Do you have more expenses? Type y" +\
                             " to input more expenses, or any key for no: ")

    return totalExpenses
```

In order to stop the loop, you press "y".

So for that matter, it does exactly what it says on the tin.
However, it is a bit illogical:

You are prompted with a question "`do you have more expenses`"

if you answer "`y`" (=yes) it stops... so you should change the `!=` to `=` and preset the `moreExpenses` variable to `y` before the loop:

```
def getExpenses():
    userExpense = 0
    totalExpenses = 0
    moreExpenses = "y"
    while moreExpenses == "y":
        userExpense = float(input("Enter an expense: "))
        totalExpenses = totalExpenses + userExpense
        moreExpenses = input("Do you have more expenses? Type y" +\
                             " to input more expenses, or any key for no: ")

    return totalExpenses
```